# How to implement "first come first served" scheduling algorithm using threading in Qt C++ programming?

Tags: qt, qt4, operating-system

I wish to add processes to a dynamic list then schedule those processes using the "first come first served" scheduling algorithm. The scheduling algorithm should only run a max of 5 processes concurrently and when a process has been terminated it should it should emit a signal to indicate termination.

Then when a process has been terminated, another process should be scheduled by the scheduling algorithm once there are processes in the queue.

Note also that each process has access to a shared list of integer which only one process can access at a time. I already know how to do this part by locking the shared integer list using QMutex. Ideally, I am seeking an example, so I can understand it.

```
//mutex example
QMutex mutex
while(!mutex->tryLock()){
    //enter code here
}
this->performTask(); // 
mutex.unlock();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have 5 instances of a class that extends [QThread](http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/qthread.html). Each class will execute a [QProcess](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qprocess.html) and wait for it to finish.

```
class MyThread : public QThread
{
public:
    MyThread(MyScheduler& aScheduler)
    :   iScheduler(aScheduler)
    {
    }

    void ExecuteProgram(const QString& aProgramName)
    {
        iProgramName = aProgramName;
        start();
    }

    void run()
    {
        iProcess.start(iProgramName);
        iProcess.waitForFinished(-1);
        iScheduler.SignalProgramTerminated(this);
    }

private:
    MyScheduler& iScheduler;  // This is your FCFS scheduler.
    QString iProgramName;
    QProcess iProcess;
};
```

(I haven't compiled this but it should give you some headway).

Comment: thanks will be trying it out and let you know as soon as possible @James

Comment: by the way is Myscheduler some built in qt or c++ class? @James

Comment: @Hue It's a class you have to write. It implements your scheduling algorithm

Comment: Sup classing QThread is not a good idea see http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/

Comment: @JustMaximumPower - i have read up that sub classing QThread is not the suggested way of threading in Qt. Thus, i have reimplemented my QThreads. I am currently working on a solution to the problem. I have almost solved it and will post soon

Comment: @James - i am currently making a solution to my problem and i have took the concept of the scheduler class and it works like a charm. I am currently finishing up the code. I will post the solution soon

Answer (score 0):

You could use QThreadPool to create a pool of 5 threads that run your processes and use QQueue to queue the pending processes in a FIFO fashion.

edit:
About mutexes:
The mutex protects a piece of code form beeing executed by more than one thread. A thread tying to lock a mutex will be blocked until no other thread holds the lock. The easiest way to use mutexes is with the QMutexLocker.

```
void myclass::modifyList(IntegerList* list)
{
    QMutexLocker lock(list->getMutex()); //this will block if an other thread holds the mutes 

    //do stuff
}
```